# How can I add a session/login servlet to get a session object for a Spring - Apache CXF backend?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, cxf, jax-rs

I have a whole lot of REST webservices developed with CXF and managed in a spring application container, and I have been tasked with creating a servlet that will create a session object that will store attributes which will be read within the Jax-RS services.

I have tried just adding a simple JEE servlet to collect the parameters and create the session object, but then I couldn't figure out how to inject that session object for use throughout the application. I have also tried adding spring-mvc and springweb to the application, and using a dispatcher servlet, which should make it easier to get the session object in each of the webservice beans. Adding two dependencies for a simple servlet seems like overkill, and moreover, spring-mvc doesn't seem to play nice with Jax-RS, the "/rest/" path that I had all the services running on before seems to be taken over by spring-mvc (jax-rs can no longer initialize endpoints on that path) even though I am using a completely different path for the session servlet.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/session")
public class SessionController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doGet(ModelMap model) {
  return "sessionPage";
} 

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost(ModelMap model) {
  return "redirect:mainpage";
  }
}
```

At the moment the frontend is in React.js, all interactions with the backend are through REST service calls. I've been trying to add a "login" page in a JSP, it's not really a login page yet, it just needs to get the userId for the moment and make that available to the backend.

```
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml", "classpath:META-    INF/cxf    /cxf-servlet.xml"})
public class CXFSetup {

@Autowired 
private Bus cxfBus;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried just adding a simple JEE servlet to collect the
>   parameters and create the session object, but then I couldn't figure
>   out how to inject that session object for use throughout the
>   application.

You could inject the current request object to your rest service and retrieve the session from it

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@Path("/yourPath")
public class SomeService {

    @Context HttpServletRequest request;

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")   
    public Object serviceMethod(){

         HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
         session.getAttribute(.....)
```